# Media Recorder is going black when recording and working only on phones which doesn't have notch

Tags: android, surfaceview, mediarecorder

I am using recordable surface for video recording. I am trying to prepare media-recorder setting up all the attributes along with videoSize width and height. It works just fine for all the phones but doesn't work for phones with notches. I am tweaking height and sometimes able to see the preview. But if i keep it default to all devices by setting up display height and width fro displayMetrics it works for some phones and doesn't work for my PIXEL3 XL phone. Please help.

This is how i am setting up my media recorder with init method.

```
private void resetVideoFragment() {
        logger.info("Resetting Video Fragment ");
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        if (videoRenderer == null) {
            videoRenderer = new Renderer(this, width, height);
        }
        setupVideoFragment(videoRenderer);
        viewHolder.liveSurfaceView.resume();
        videoFile = getVideoFile();
        try {
            viewHolder.liveSurfaceView.initRecorder(videoFile, width, height, (mr, what, extra) -> {
                logger.error("Media Recorder error " + " what: " + what + " extra: " + extra);
            }, (mr, what, extra) -> {
                logger.error("Media Recorder Info " + " what: " + what + " extra: " + extra);
            });
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            logger.error("Couldn't re-init recording " + iox);
        }
    }
```

This is how my init mediarecorder method looks like

```
public void initRecorder(File saveToFile, int displayWidth, int displayHeight,
                             int orientationHint, MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener,
                             MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener) {

        MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
        mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);

        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mediaRecorder.setInputSurface(mSurface);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);

        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(displayWidth, displayHeight);
(On phone which doesn't work If i try to tweak this height and width
 it able to shows preview if i increase more number to it and
 it throws to the error i was talking about while recording
How to make it work for all the phones ?)

        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

        // original setting-- resulted in a huge file in just a few seconds!!
//        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(12000000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(7500000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientationHint);

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(saveToFile.getPath());
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurface);
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("IO Exception on Media Recorder init method: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        mMediaRecorder = mediaRecorder;

    }
```

error code of what: 100 extra: 2 
and what: 268435556 extra: -1007 when recording